# how do I get a preview of a java swing application without actually running it?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

Is it possible to get a good preview of the java swing application without running it repeatedly in IntelliJ? Whenever I modify code I have to run it again and again so that it looks good.

It also generates a bunch of classes that I don't really need since I'm committing to a GitHub repository How do I do this?

Comment: There are some GUI builders. Netbeans used an XML form file for layouting. It might be a better idea to decouple View (your GUI code) from Model and Controller and let a test controller show the form, maybe in several states. Such a "Test" Driven Development is actually very fast.

Comment: Please check this option: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/previewing-forms.html

Comment: I can't really do it though. any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about IntelliJ, but Eclipse has [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), a visual designer and development tool that supports Swing. You can install it into a variety of Eclipse releases, I don't think it comes pre-installed in any of the Eclipse packages.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse and NetBeans does have some WindowBuilder future

if you are using eclipse download [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=4008412)

and if you are using Netbeans it does provide a WindowBuilder itself so read [this article](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html)

Comment: thanks. Found that no plugins are available for this(I'm on intellij).